# SQL query results in UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: response is not defined

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

I am trying to display specific data from a table in mysql using this code. I am in between using a for loop but it says that `res` or `response` is not defined. What do I need to edit or change in my code below?

```
function lowInventory() {
    console.log("View all product that are low in inventory...\n");
    for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
        connection.query("SELECT stock_quantity (*) FROM products WHERE stock_quantity < 5", function (err, res) {
            if (err) throw err;
            //log all results of the SELECT statement
            console.table(Response);
            connection.end();
        });
    }
}
```

I need for it to display results of quantity that is less than 5 in node.js from my table.

Answer (score 0):

change console.table(Response) to console.log(Response)